# Strange behavior when closing a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

- Work workbook is called `Main.xlsm`
- It has two sheets called `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`
- `Sheet1` has a commandbutton called `cmd_btn`
- `Sheet2` is currently `xlVeryHidden`

---

In `Module1` I have the following code:

```
Sub Macro1()
With Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Visible = True
    .Copy
    .Visible = xlVeryHidden
End With
End Sub
```

This code makes `Sheet2` visible, copies it as a new workbook (a new workbook pops up), then makes it `xlVeryHidden` again. At this point, Main.xlsm is behind, newly created workbook is in front.

---

When I run `Macro1` directly:

- I click the X (close) button of Main.xlsm, the Main.xlsm tries to
  close as it should be.

When I run `Macro1` from `cmd_btn`:

- This time the excel window flickers a few times. When I click the X
  (close) button of Main.xlsm, the newly opened excel workbook
  (Book#.xlsx) tries to close.

**Question:** What might be the reason of this?

---

**PS:** If this doesn't happen to you when you try the above, try the following and you will experience the same thing:

- Create a combobox on `Sheet1` called `cmb_list`
- Populate `cmb_list` with "Copy Sheet2" and "Copy Sheet3"
- Create another sheet called `Sheet3` and make it `xlVeryHidden`
- Select any of the values in `cmb_list` and run the following code from `cmd_btn`

---

```
Sub Macro3()
With Workbooks("Main.xlsm")
    If cmb_list.Value = "Copy Sheet2" Then
        .Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
        .Sheets("Sheet2").Copy
        .Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    ElseIf cmb_list.Value = "Copy Sheet3" Then
        .Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = True
        .Sheets("Sheet3").Copy
        .Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Could one of the issues be, when you copy the sheet, the new wb is the active workbook. So when it hides the sheet, you get the flicker. possibly add at the beginning `Application.ScreenUpdating = 0`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all steps you provided and couldn't duplicate the problem with your code, as is
(do you have any other code in Workbook_BeforeClose() event?)

I optimized the code a bit and it still works:

> **Sheet1** VBA module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmd_btn_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    CopyWorkSheet Right(cmb_list.Value, 1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

> **ThisWorkbook** VBA module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    populateCmb
End Sub
```

---

> **Module1**:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub populateCmb()
    With Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").cmb_list
        .AddItem "Copy Sheet2"
        .AddItem "Copy Sheet3"
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub CopyWorkSheet(ByVal wsID As Long)
    With Workbooks("Main.xlsm")
        With .Sheets("Sheet" & wsID)
            .Visible = True
            .Copy
            .Visible = xlVeryHidden
        End With
        .Close False    'Closes Main.xlsm, without saving it
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for optimising the code but I still have the same issue. I tried it on another computer and it has the same issue. Any idea why? (This happens in my big project excel, but since this is an issue, I made a new excel just to test this issue, so I do not have any other code in the excel.)

Comment: @HappyForever: Do you still see the issue in the new file? If yes, do you have any add-ons loading? If no, there must be other code in the original file causing it - try placing a break point in `cmd_btn_Click()` and stepping through the code line by line to check what other statements are being executed

Comment: @HappyForever can you also show the Sub for `cmd_btn_Click()`, and qualify the cmb_list object: `If Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").cmb_list.Value = "Copy Sheet2" Then`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have no add-ons loading. As I said, the problem is still there with minimal code in the new excel file. My `cmd_btn_Click()` sub has the macro name of the called sub. ie. Macro1, or Macro3. Nothing else in the `cmd_btn_Click()`. Hope this helps